# Question on lim sup

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Given that $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence. If $b_n=\sup\{a_n,a_{n+1},a_{n+2},a_{n+3},\ldots\}$
prove that $\lim\sup(a_n)$ is a limit of $b_n$.

The lim sup is defined as l.u.b. of $$A = \{x\in R| \ x < a_n\ \  \text{for an infinite number of values of}\ \  n\}$$

So far I have proven that the points in $b_n$ are the upper bounds of $A$, and I want to use the property that $b_n$ is a decreasing and bounded sequence to say that $l.u.b.A$ is the limit of $b_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write the sequence as $(x_n)$ (instead of $(a_n)$) and say $\alpha \leq x_n \leq \beta$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Considering $X_n=\{x_n, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2},\ldots\}$ and writing $b_n = \sup X_n$ and $a_n = \inf X_n$ we have that

$$\underbrace{\alpha \leq a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \ldots \leq  a_n}_{\color{green}{\text{monotonic non- decreasing}}} \leq \ldots \leq \underbrace{b_n \leq \ldots \leq b_2 \leq b_1 \leq \beta}_{\color{blue}{\text{monotonic non-increasing}}}$$

Thefore the sequences are bounded and monotonic, thus convergent then

$$a = \lim a_n = \sup a_n = \sup_{n}\inf X_n\\b=\lim b_n = \inf b_n = \inf_{n} \sup X_n$$

**Edit:**

Example: Let the sequence $(x_n)$ be given by $x_{2n-1} = -\frac{1}{n}$ and $x_{2n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$.

We have that $\inf X_{2n-2} = \inf X_{2n-1} = -\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sup X_{2n-1} = \sup X_{2n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$, then

$$\lim \inf x_n = 0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \lim \sup x_n = 1$$

Comment: By $x_n$, what sequence do you mean?

Comment: Just to make it easier to use the symbols.

Comment: are you referring to the sequence $a_n$?

Comment: That's right, is the same bounded sequence, just changed to $(x_n)$

Comment: Could you explain the part where you said $b = limb_n$ in slightly more detail?

Comment: I get the fact that they are convergent, but how to you get b = $inf\ b_n$?

Comment: Better to see that in an example, what do you say?

Comment: I see that the infimum of $b_n$ is the limit because it is the smallest value (the sequence is monotonic decreasing)

Comment: But I don't get how you went on to the next part.

Comment: For each set $X_n$ you take, if there exists, the supremum and as $n$ goes to infinity you will find a limit which is going to be the least upper bound of this new sequence of points.

Comment: Think of $\{\frac{1}{n} ; n \in \mathbb N\}$ what is the infimum of this set? Or the supremum of this set $\{\frac{n}{n+1}; n \in \mathbb N\}$? You also call it the limit of the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $y_n = \frac{n}{n+1}$, right? It's the same idea here. you're taking the limit of subsequences of a sequence, defined as limit point.

Comment: If you have any more questions feel free to ask.